# codeception codecoverage of acceptance tests

Tags: codeception

I make my first steps with codeceptions code coverage and c3.php. I configured everything as explained in the documentation: http://codeception.com/docs/11-Codecoverage#Remote-CodeCoverage

I want to start with the acceptance tests. For testing reasons I deleted all feature files. But when I run the test with

```
vendor/bin/codecept run acceptance --coverage-html
```

I saw a coverage coverage of 33% for methodes and 89% for lines .
[image]

How is this possible? I expected a codecoverage of 0%

For the case that this is an error I opend an issue https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/4069

Answer (score 0):

I was not aware, that it was not allowed to include the c3.php in one of my test files.

That was the solution: https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/4069